# In Windows 10 Univeral getting XML from URL and show the information in ListView

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm new here but used the community a lot for research. But now I couldn't find an answer on my specific problem.

I'm creating an universal app for Windows 10 for my university. One function every student wants to have is to see what's there in the canteen.

I've already talked to the guys providing the information on the internet for our canteen and I'm allowed to use them in my app (I did that, because some of you mentioned copyright problems by parsing information from websites...).

Now I'd like to get these information form an URL and create a ListView (or something better?) from it to show all necessary information in my app.

Unfortunately I didn't find any tutorial how to do this. So I thought you might help me (or have a better idea how to do this).

The URL where I'd like to parse the information is: [XML Data](https://www.studentenwerk-oberfranken.de/?eID=bwrkSpeiseplanRss&tx_bwrkspeiseplan_pi2%5Bbar%5D=340&tx_bwrkspeiseplan_pi2%5Bdate%5D=2016-03-22)

And this is the link where the information are show nicely: [Canteen Website](https://www.studentenwerk-oberfranken.de/essen/speiseplaene/hof.html)

I really hope you can help me with this and thank you for your great work!

SAR-71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever it comes to situation when one have to GET something from the Web, one  should reach for [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) ([Win 10 sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)). The code for downloading your XML could look something like this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("<your_uri>");
httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Where `httpReponseBody` is your XML

When it comes to parsing XML I would suggest using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx). You can find samples of usage by simply searching for the

> LINQ to XML examples

in google, but there're some basic queries [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Ale_lipa ! Thank you very much for your help! I've tried your code and with little changes it worked perfectly! Now I get the XML to do all necessary stuff with it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure is on my side ;]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. I feel obliged to tell you that an important rule for StackOverflow question is to provide sample code, to show proof of an attempt at tackling the problem. The people here are not here to code your project for you, but are happy to help if you have a specific and well defined issue you are dealing with.

However, I will try to provide a starting point for your project.

First, what you are looking to do is called "web scraping"

If you are programming a Windows 10 App, I assume you are doing so in C#, and are proficient with it.

One library which handles this called HTMLAgilityPack.

A basic use case for yourself would be:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();  
HtmlDocument document = web.Load("https://www.studentenwerk-oberfranken.de/?eID=bwrkSpeiseplanRss&tx_bwrkspeiseplan_pi2%5Bbar%5D=340&tx_bwrkspeiseplan_pi2%5Bdate%5D=2016-03-22");
```

I note that there is a date in that URL, but I will assume you know how to change that date to match the current date.

A more thorough explanation can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/).

Now that you have the XML, you need to parse the XML for the relevant information. Thankfully, C# has an object called XmlReader.

Now, Microsoft has very good documentation for the XmlReader, which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx).

If you reach a specific issue or blocking point, don't hesitate to open a new question, but with a snippet of the code which you suspect is causing the issue, and a detailed description of what you intend it to do, and what is it doing which you don't intend it to do.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Wong ! Thank you for your help and sorry for not posting code! I've just asked another question and posted it this time with code ;) Your links are a great help for me and I'll try using the XmlReader... And yes I'm coding in C#